# Issiue with Binding Data WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I've issue with data Binding. It doesn't refresh. 
I've ViewModel:

```
public partial class AutomaticTestingViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private TemperatureSensorStates _temperatureSensors;

    public AutomaticTestingViewModel()
    {
        CreateAllObservableCollestions();
    }

    public TemperatureSensorStates TemperatureSensors
    {
        get { return _temperatureSensors; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _temperatureSensors, value); }
    }

    private void CreateAllObservableCollestions()
    {
        TemperatureSensors = new TemperatureSensorStates();
    }
}
```

TemperatureSensor class is defined in another file:

```
public class TemperatureSensorStates : BindableBase
{
    private decimal _cpuTemperatureSensor;
    private decimal _insideTemperatureSensor;

    public decimal CpuTemperatureSensor
    {
        get
        {
            return _cpuTemperatureSensor;
        }
        set
        {   
            Log.InfoFormat("CPU temperature setter");
            SetProperty(ref _cpuTemperatureSensor, value);
        }
    }

    public decimal InsideTemperatureSensor
    {
        get { return _insideTemperatureSensor; }
        set
        {
            Log.InfoFormat("Inside sensor temperature setter");
            SetProperty(ref _insideTemperatureSensor, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I added logs to the setter, it's working fine, and in the log I've the proper value after it has changed but my binding in WPF freezes and I see no value change in the window. (The first value is shown).

**My binding**

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding TemperatureSensors.CpuTemperatureSensor}" Foreground="PaleVioletRed"
```

Can somebody find the cause why the binding doesn't work (the value in the window doesn't refresh)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this link. It may help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15822/Bind-Better-with-INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Problem solved. Binding was OK. I've SetProperty so it is simillar to OnPropertyChanged. I'd two instances of ViewModel. Thats why it wasn't correct.